# How do I resize nodes in the node editor?

Tags: node-editor

How do I make my nodes smaller? My nodes currently look like the top one, but a node from someone else's .blend file look like the bottom one. How do I make mine look like the bottom one? I can resize them horizontally, but not vertically.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out, click top right icon which looks like material icon. This will collapse render layer preview thumbnail and make node smaller.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> that will hide any unused sockets

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial and thoroughly explain the solution and required workflow. One liners and short tips rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the procedure and why it works feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be deleted or converted into a comment. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: While a useful tip, answer already present above is the solution to that given question since it will collapse node's thumbnail and make it smaller without removing any node output sockets. Ctrl+H will do nothing in this case since no output sockets should be removed from the node (*before* and *after* screenshots showcase that)